# get shapes of type dropdown list

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-interop, excel-automation

This is some horrendous code which I would like to improve:

```
Excel.Shapes theShapes = excelSheet.Shapes;

foreach (Excel.Shape aShape in theShapes)
{    
    foreach (var groupItem in aShape.GroupItems)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.TypeName(groupItem));       
        var s = (Excel.Shape) groupItem;
        if (s is Excel.OLEObject) continue;
        try
        {
            if (s.FormControlType == Excel.XlFormControl.xlDropDown)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("### " + s.Name);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to obtain drop down lists easier? How can I avoid the above exception when I try to obtain the FormControlType?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the `try...cath` with a condition confirming that it is a `FormControl`.

```
Excel.Shapes theShapes = excelSheet.Shapes;

foreach (Excel.Shape aShape in theShapes)
{    
    foreach (var groupItem in aShape.GroupItems)
    {
        var s = (Excel.Shape) groupItem;
        if (s is Excel.OLEObject) continue;

        if (s.Type == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType.msoFormControl)
        {
           if (s.FormControlType == Excel.XlFormControl.xlDropDown)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("### " + s.Name);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it does not work - it never hits anything below if (aShape.Type == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType.msoFormControl).

Comment: @csetzkorn ?! It should. Are you sure that you are looking for a dropdown? Perhaps are you looking for a combobox. The dropdown is created while filtering data; the combobox is one of the controls you add from the developer tab.

Comment: @csetzkorn actually I tested it right now and this code locates both: comboboxes and dropdowns. Are you perhaps relying on ActiveX elements?

Comment: I think the problem - in my scenario - is the grouping aShape.Type == msoGroup (see also my second for each loop). I have to say that I inherited that GUI and it must have been grouped.

Comment: @csetzkorn One second: are you saying that your original loop works fine (although it is just a bit dirty because of relying on the try... catch)?

Comment: @csetzkorn then the solution is clear (look at my updated answer). Sorry, you did explain your point rightly but I (wrongly) thought that (non-ActiveX) shapes might be accessed anyway without looking at groups, apparently I was wrong.